# How to insert duplicated values in dictionary?

Tags: python

I have `dct = {'word1': 23, 'word2': 12, 'word1' : 7, 'word2':2}` and I need to get list when keys dont duplicate and contain all values of from dictionary

f.e.:
`lst = ('word1 23 7', 'word2 12 2')`

Is there any possibility to make it like this in Python?

Comment: You can't *have* "dct = {'word1': 23, 'word2': 12, 'word1' : 7, 'word2':2}". Try this in an interpreter. Do you have several dictionaries as input ?

Comment: If you allow for duplicate keys, it's not a dictionary anymore

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7706981/78845

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can't* have what you describe.  You *could* have this:

```
dct = {}

dct['word1'] = 23
dct['word2'] = 12
dct['word1'] = 7
dct['word2'] = 2
```

But at the end all you'd end up with is this:

```
{'word1': 7, 'word2': 2}
```

Keys in a dictionary cannot be repeated.  If your code is actually set up like my first example, what you may want is this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)

dct['word1'].append(23)
dct['word2'].append(12)
dct['word1'].append(7)
dct['word2'].append(2)
```

After which you'll have this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'word1': [23, 7], 'word2': [12, 2]})
```

Comment: It looks to me that what OP is looking for is a `set` valued `dict` rather than a `list` valued `dict`.

Comment: thx i didnt know. so it useless dct for this case. So i have list of strings like this: 'word1 23' 'word 1 12' word1 65' 'word2 23' etc. so what I need is to create new list where words will not repeated but will contain all rows where they occure. f.e.: word1 23 12 65, more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706981/how-to-split-and-compare-part-of-string-in-list