# How to remove duplicates in strings within list?

Tags: python

I have list of string but in each string is duplicate I need to remove.
f.e.:

```
lst = ('word1 2 36 2 2' ' word2 96 5 5 5 14' 'word3 45 6 45 45')
```

etc.

I need:

```
lst = ('word1 2 36' 'word2 96 5 14' 'word3 45 6')
```

Comment: These don't look like Python `list`s, but anyway, with which part of the algorithm are you stuck? Show us what you've tried so far and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 3):

Generally:

1. Create a `dictionary` for each key *wordN*
2. In this key, convert item *2* through *n* of `list` to a `set`
3. Iterate through the dictionary, building a new list from each key and its set's contents

Comment: Sounds a bit like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706621/how-to-insert-duplicated-values-in-dictionary/7706691#7706691) to one of the OP's earlier questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, and as-written your "list" isn't a list but a string. I guess you probably meant to make it a tuple, but even then you need commas between the items.

In the following example, we iterate over the items, split the string [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function, add the items to a [set](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), join them together again with the string [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), and append them to our output list (a real list this time):

```
>>> lst = ('word1 2 36 2 2', ' word2 96 5 5 5 14', 'word3 45 6 45 45')
>>> out = []
>>> for item in lst:
...   tokens = item.split()
...   s = set(tokens)
...   joined = " ".join(s)
...   out.append(joined)
... 
>>> out
['2 word1 36', '96 5 14 word2', '45 word3 6']
```

This can be written more compactly with a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = ('word1 2 36 2 2', ' word2 96 5 5 5 14', 'word3 45 6 45 45')
>>> out = [" ".join(set(item.split())) for item in lst]
>>> out
['2 word1 36', '96 5 14 word2', '45 word3 6']
```

Comment: yes sorry I forgot commas, but to be more specific I need to maintain order, it must be 1st word1 and after numbers in the same order as before, because words will not duplicate, only numbers, so I need to leave word on the left side and remove duplicate just from numbers

Comment: Then do what Alex wrote above.

Comment: Also, you should explain WHY you want to do something in your posts. You're getting a lot of downvotes because your questions are sloppy and don't give any context. Do you really need strings back? If so, why? Why do you need to maintain order? What have to tried up to now? If you explain the larger picture you'll probably get more useful answers (ie. answers that teach you something rather than answering your narrow and possibly "wrong" question).

Comment: so in my program the input is textfiile, and I need to make another textfile with all words from input file and numbers of rows where are those words occured. Words and numbers cant be duplicated. So now I have list with those words and if I make output file from it it seems like:word1 2 2 2 2 2 word2 2 5 6 2 2 word3 25 26 89 25 25. But every word is at new line and ist duplicated. So only problem is duplicated in numbers.At the beggining I remove chars like ? ! . , " etc. after I put it into 2 separates tuples a I'vs made defaultdict(list) to put more then one value to one key.....

Comment: ........... after I'vs made output = [key + " " + str(dct[key]) for key in dct], so now I have output but there are stiill duplicates numbers (dct[key]). and I dont know how to remove duplicate, if I schoud do it in output, or before in dct I dont know how